# Using boost::test with Visual Studio 2010 - how to view test output?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, visual-c++, boost

I'm using boost::test with Visual Studio 2010, in a Win32 console project. boost::test appears to take care of the `main()` function, by providing its own. It looks like I don't have to provide a `main()`.

Thing is, I want my console output not to disappear immediately, but this means that I'd have to define the `main()` function somehow, to get it to stay on screen. Thing is any attempts I make to redefine `main()` appear to get ignored.

I know that Cppunit can output test results during compilation - does boost::test have anything like this?

Answer (score 6):

I use this configuration: In one solution I have a main project and a test project; the main project depends on the test project; the test project has a post-build event with $(TargetPath) which runs the test project and redirects the output to the output-window. Test errors can be located by double-clicking on the corresponding line in the output window.

Answer (score 3):

Ctrl+F5 - start without debugging.  This will keep the output window open.

Answer (score 0):

You might try out [**Gallio**](http://gallio.org) in combination with the [**Boost test adapter for Gallio**](https://github.com/ndl/Gallio.BoostAdapter) from [Alexander Tsvyashchenko](http://www.ndl.kiev.ua/content/gallio-adapter-boosttest). The interesting part is that you will benefit all the goodies of Gallio (test output, filtering, reports, and integration with many 3th party tools such as CC.Net, NAnt, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/test/doc/html/utf/usage-recommendations/dot-net-specific.html) is described how to setup your project to get what you want.

Comment: This is the same answer as the one by @hmuelner, just in form of a non-informative link instead of nicely spelled out.